# Benchmark my lumen application

Tags: php, laravel, benchmarking, lumen, php-7.1

We had build an application in lumen. Now we need to benchmark each api request that hit our application.

Is there any way to do it?

I tried to google in all possible ways I know.

All I need is to find out which request or function is taking long time. Is there any possibility do it?

Comment: Use XDebug profiler if you want to find bottlenecks

Comment: I'm not user about bottlenecks. Could you be more specific.

Comment: This is the XDebug profiler documentation: https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler